# MP4Parser Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, mp4parser

I'm facing a problem to append an audio, that I recorded using
     android.media.MediaRecorder.MediaRecorder() 
to a video that I took using the camera intent.

Basically, when I try to do this:

```
Movie s = MovieCreator.build(audioPath);
```

I get an exception:

```
12-05 22:04:30.775: E/AndroidRuntime(4191): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 22:04:30.775: E/AndroidRuntime(4191): at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:48)
```

The path in this case is:

```
video: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/merged_20131205_221045.3gp audio:
/mnt/sdcard/audio_1386288700940.3gp
```

I have combined two videos with success. But I face this problem to combine a sound in a video.
Actually, the problem is not to combine, the exception is when I call `MovieCreator.build(audioPath)`.

Have anyone already faced this problem and can help me?

Comment: is `MovieCreator` a class or object?

Comment: Its a class but I am also getting the same crash when building audio using Moviereator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I related this problem a long time ago and until now the same issue happens.
I stopped using [MP4Parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) and started using [FFmpeg4Android](http://ffmpeg4android.netcompss.com/).

It's not free and a little expensive ($499), depending on your project. But for me, it was perfect. It works very well and you can do a lot of things that MP4Parser doesn't allow you to do.

But there's a lot of ffmpeg free libraries for Android. By the time I posted this problem, 2013, I didn't find a free lib working without problems. But for sure today must be a free library that works very well.

Another option is to build your own ffmpeg library for Android. Here is a guide for this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android

Hope it helps someone.